# How to change fontsize of only x or y labels in seaborn pairplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, font-size

I use a sample code to make a pairplot by seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins, corner=True)
```

I would like to change the font size of x and y labels only (not xticks / yticks). I am aware of `sns.set(font_scale=k)`, but it affects all texts (x-y labels, x-y ticks). However, I want to change font size of only x-y lables.

If you have any idea. please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`seaborn.plotting_context`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html#seaborn-plotting-context) like below:

*(as your question in the comment If you write like below after this, Modified values reset and back to default)*

```
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
with sns.plotting_context(rc={"axes.labelsize":20}):
    sns.pairplot(penguins, corner=True)
```

> seaborn.plotting_context
>
> > Parameters :
> >
> > rcdict, optional
> > Parameter mappings to override the values in the preset seaborn context dictionaries. This only updates parameters that are considered part of the context definition.

**With `rc dict` you can change each below styles**

```
{'axes.linewidth': 1.875,
 'grid.linewidth': 1.5,
 'lines.linewidth': 2.25,
 'lines.markersize': 9.0,
 'patch.linewidth': 1.5,
 'xtick.major.width': 1.875,
 'ytick.major.width': 1.875,
 'xtick.minor.width': 1.5,
 'ytick.minor.width': 1.5,
 'xtick.major.size': 9.0,
 'ytick.major.size': 9.0,
 'xtick.minor.size': 6.0,
 'ytick.minor.size': 6.0,
 'font.size': 18.0,
 'axes.labelsize': 18.0,
 'axes.titlesize': 18.0,
 'xtick.labelsize': 16.5,
 'ytick.labelsize': 16.5,
 'legend.fontsize': 16.5,
 'legend.title_fontsize': 18.0}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I reset it to default value? So, it won't affect other plots.

Comment: @Mohammad edited answer

Comment: Thanks again. Last question: As you can see, in the first row, the y_label (bill_length_mm) is not shown. Do you possibly know how to show it?

Comment: @Mohammad welcome, this is default because you use `corner = True` and in the first row you have one element and you don't need because both of them `bill_length_mm` and other row have more than one element and you need label for both `x-axis` , `y-axis`